# how do I unit test with multiple expect

Tags: dart, dart-unittest, dart-mock

The unit test I write below doesn't work when there are 3 expect, how can I rewrite the unit test below:

```
test('400 bad response', () async {
  when(
    () => sampleClient.getTransaction(
        '1'),
  ).thenThrow(DioError(
      response: Response(
          statusCode: 400,
          data: badRepsonseJson,
          requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '')),
      requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: '')));
  final call = sampleService.getTransactionByHash(
      '1');

  expect(() => call, throwsA(TypeMatcher<SampleException>())); // Expect 1
  try {
    await sampleService.getTransactionByHash(
        '1');
  } on SampleException catch (e) {
    expect(e.errorCode, badResponse.statusCode); // Expect 2
    expect(e.message, badResponse.message); // Expect 3
  }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens?  Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

> ```dart
> final call = sampleService.getTransactionByHash(
>     '1');
>
> expect(() => call, throwsA(TypeMatcher<SampleException>())); // Expect 1
> ```

I would not expect that `expect` to succeed.  Invoking `() => call` just returns the already computed value of the `call` variable, which cannot fail.

If you instead expect `sampleService.getTransactionByHash('1');` to throw an exception, then you need to invoke that in your callback to `expect`:

```dart
expect(
  () => sampleService.getTransactionByHash('1'),
  throwsA(TypeMatcher<SampleException>()),
);
```

Comment: Alternatively, `call` is a `Future`, because `getTransactionByHash` is async, in which case you should just do `expect(call, throwsA(...));`.